# Finding Gavril and Olga Friedmann of Arad, Romania?

Tags: romania

I am looking for a family called Friedmann (Gavril and Olga). In 1942 they lived in Arad, Romania. Olga was born around 1900 in Oradea area and moved with her husband in Arad. These are the only info that I have.

Where can I see if they went to Israel after?

Comment: When were Friedmann and Olga born? If it was after 1918, we need to be sure we're adhering to our privacy policy https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic which forbids identification of living or possibly living individuals.

Comment: You may already be familiar with it but https://genealogy.org.il/resources/resource-guide-romania/ may help.

Comment: Thank you. No, they are not born after 1918. Olga was born around 1900 in Oradea area and moved with her husband in Arad. These are the only info that I have.